# как выровнять содержимое listView?

Tags: java, javafx

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли как-то выровнять содержимое? Или только нужно создавать tableView?

Comment: Там три label без фиксированного размера, а сама строка HBox?

Comment: @Maxim сверху да,а все остальное выводится просто в listView

Comment: А, у вас стандартная реализация ячейки. Вам нужно сделать собственную сложную ячейку, в нее же сразу сможете перенести кнопки удалить и очистить. https://www.turais.de/how-to-custom-listview-cell-in-javafx/

Comment: @Maxim мне нужно чтобы данные выводились в listView ровно.А ни как на скрине.Возможно ли это в Listview?

Comment: Да, Вам нужно сделать в listView составную ячейку, которую можно сверстать как угодно (например как вы сделали шапку). Ячейка в listView верстается аналогичным способом как и сама верстка приложения.

Answer (score 0):

Простой пример:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        ListView<DirectoryInfo> listView = new ListView<>();
        listView.getItems().addAll(
                new DirectoryInfo("Курсовая работа", 6, 275),
                new DirectoryInfo("ЧисленныеМетоды", 4, 0),
                new DirectoryInfo("Политология", 1, 543),
                new DirectoryInfo("Матанализ", 1, 100),
                new DirectoryInfo("ООП", 3, 1753)
        );
        listView.setCellFactory(param -> new DirectoryInfoListCell());

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(listView,300, 300));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private static class DirectoryInfo {

        public DirectoryInfo(String directory, int countFiles, double size) {
            this.directory = directory;
            this.countFiles = countFiles;
            this.size = size;
        }

        String directory;
        int countFiles;
        double size;
    }

    private static class DirectoryInfoListCell extends ListCell<DirectoryInfo> {

        private Label lDirectory;
        private Label lCountFiles;
        private Label lSize;
        private HBox hbContent;

        public DirectoryInfoListCell() {
            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(DirectoryInfo item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (empty) {
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                if (hbContent == null) {
                    initContent();
                }
                lDirectory.setText(item.directory);
                lCountFiles.setText(String.valueOf(item.countFiles));
                lSize.setText(String.valueOf(item.size));
                setGraphic(hbContent);
            }
        }

        private void initContent() {
            lDirectory = new Label();
            lDirectory.setMinWidth(150);

            lCountFiles = new Label();
            lCountFiles.setMinWidth(100);

            lSize = new Label();
            lSize .setMinWidth(100);

            hbContent = new HBox(lDirectory, lCountFiles, lSize);
        }
    }

}
```